# How to send message using rest API of ejabberd from android?

Tags: android, ejabberd

I am trying to send a message to a server using ejabberd rest API. When I send using POSTMAN it works perfectly but when I send from my android device using the OKHTTP library it always gives me an exception of **unexpected end of stream on Connection{192.168.1.24:5443, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=/192.168.1.24:5443 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}** here is my ejabberd.yml file

```
hosts:
  - "faiqkhan-VirtualBox"

loglevel: 4
log_rotate_size: 10485760
log_rotate_count: 1

certfiles:
  - "/home/faiqkhan/ejabberd-20.07/conf/server.pem"

ca_file: "/home/faiqkhan/ejabberd-20.07/conf/cacert.pem"

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: false
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
      "/api": mod_http_api
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/captcha": ejabberd_captcha
      "/upload": mod_http_upload
      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
      "/api": mod_http_api
  -
    port: 1883
    ip: "::"
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000

s2s_use_starttls: optional

acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128
      - ::FFFF:127.0.0.1/128
      - ::FFFF:172.0.0.1/16
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@faiqkhan-VirtualBox"
    ip:
      - ::FFFF:172.19.0.0/16
access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    allow: local

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          acl: loopback
          acl: admin
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        access:
          allow:
            acl: loopback
            acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - status
      - connected_users_number

shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast

max_fsm_queue: 10000

acme:
   contact: "mailto:admin@faiqkhan-VirtualBox"
   ca_url: "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"

allow_contrib_modules: true

modules:
  mod_stanza_ack: {}
  mod_http_offline: {}
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: https://@HOST@:5443/upload
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: never
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      allow_subscription: true  # enable MucSub
      mam: false
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ip_access: all
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_vcard:
    search: true
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false
```

And my client side code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
.add("type", "normal")
.add("from", "admin@faiqkhan-virtualbox")
.add("to", "faiq@faiqkhan-virtualbox")
.add("subject", "")
.add("body", "In 5 minutes")
.build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
.url("http://192.168.1.24:5443/api/send_message")
.addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
.addHeader("Connection","close")
.post(formBody)
.build();
try {
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Am I miss something which is important to send a message using the REST API of ejabberd?

Comment: I see in your config that 5443 port has tls:true, but later in your client code, the URL is http instead of https.

Comment: It worked. But now getting this error **javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.**

Comment: I just false the tls and change https to Http for a temporary basis to create my logic on the client and server-side. But getting this **Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=http://192.168.1.24:5443/api/send_message}**

Comment: I solved the issue. The reason I was getting this error is I sent request list  this : **.url("http://192.168.1.24:5443/api/send_message").post(formBody).build();** I don't know why it's not worked. When I comment this **.post(fromBody)** peace of code and send a request like this **http://192.168.1.24:5443/api/send_message?"type"= "normal",&"from"= "admin@faiqkhan-virtualbox",&"to"= "faiq@faiqkhan-virtualbox",&"subject"= "Restart",&"body"= "In 5 minutes"** it worked for me.